# StopPropogation for simultaneous click events inside HTML

Tags: html

My html file is

```
<div onclick="alert('signup');location.href='signup.jsp';" class="outerElement">
    <div onclick="alert('login');location.href='login.jsp';" class="innerElement">
      <h1>login</h1>
    </div>
    <button onclick="alert('login');location.href='login.jsp';">Add to Carts</button>
</div>
```

so how can i prevent the outer elements click event. In script event listener we can use stopPropagation. But am not using any script. What is the way to do in HTML?

Comment: use ids for a start, then you can call only onclick of that div (instead of all with that class)

Comment: why do you have 2 elements with an alert with login?